# MergeSort - Strange Behaviour when using numpy to generate test sequence

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, numpy

Following is a quick implementation of MergeSort I cooked up in python:

```
import numpy 
def mergeSort(a):
    if len(a) ==1:  
        return
    if len(a) == 2:
        if a[0] > a[1]:
            tmp = a[0]
            a[0] = a[1]
            a[1] = tmp
        return
    x = a[0:len(a)/2]
    y = a[len(a)/2:]
    mergeSort(x)
    mergeSort(y)
    j=0
    k=0
    for i in xrange(len(a)):
        if j == len(x) or k<len(y) and x[j] > y[k]:
            a[i] = y[k]
            k = k + 1
        else:
            a[i] = x[j]
            j = j + 1

a = numpy.random.randint(100, size=3) # Generates say [20  3 75]
mergeSort(a) 
print a # Yields [3, 3, 75] !
a = [20,3,75] 
mergeSort(a) 
print a # Yields [3, 20, 75] !
```

This implementation inexplicably fails when I use numpy to generate random arrays for me whereas if I hardcode exactly one of the failing numpy generated sequence and run the code, it sorts perfectly. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: NumPy arrays are not lists and don't behave like lists. For example, slicing a NumPy array produces a view of the original data, not a copy.

Comment: Did you try using strategically placed print functions to see what is happening?

Comment: That explains it, I guess. Also if you could post the quickest way to get a list from numpy I can mark it as an answer. Yes I tried printing, but couldn't figure that mutating slices of the array was mutating the original

Comment: list(a) is pretty quick

Comment: @AlanLeuthard Cool, that settles everything. Thanks

Comment: `a.tolist()` is usually better than `list(a)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy arrays don't behave the same as lists. The merge step fails because `x` and `y` would be views of `a` when `a` is a numpy array. You can pass `list(a)` to the `mergeSort` routine to make it work:

```
import numpy 
def mergeSort(a):
    if len(a) ==1:  
        return
    if len(a) == 2:
        if a[0] > a[1]:
            tmp = a[0]
            a[0] = a[1]
            a[1] = tmp
        return
    x = a[0:len(a)/2]
    y = a[len(a)/2:]
    mergeSort(x)
    mergeSort(y)
    j=0
    k=0
    for i in xrange(len(a)):
        if j == len(x) or k<len(y) and x[j] > y[k]:
            a[i] = y[k]
            k = k + 1
        else:
            a[i] = x[j]
            j = j + 1

a = numpy.random.randint(100, size=3) # Generates say [20  3 75]
a = list(a)
mergeSort(a)
a = numpy.array(a)
print a # correctly Yields [3, 20, 75] !
a = [20,3,75] 
mergeSort(a) 
print a # Yields [3, 20, 75] !
```

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning here that the failure occurs at the merge step because x and y would be views of 'a' when a is a numpy array.

Comment: That's true.  Could you change them to x = list(a[0:len(a)/2]) to fix the problem?